# Specific Hours CountdownTimer

Tags: javascript, time, timer, countdown

I am trying to make a countdown timer that will show only from 8am till 16 and then show a message for 16hours and repeat the same loop every day.
I have this code but I don't really get what is wrong with it. Any recommendations?

Appreciate. Thank you!

```
let getTom = () => {
var tom = new Date();    
tom.setDate(now.getDate() + (1 - now.getDay() % 1));
tom.setHours(16, 30, 0, 0); 
return tom; }

window.onload = function() {
var countDownDate = getTom();
let startCountdown = function() {
    // Countdown Timer
    var x = setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countDownDate - now;
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor(
            (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
        );
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        var time =
            days + " days, " + hours + "h, " + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s ";
        document.getElementById("time").innerText = time;
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("time").innerText = "test";
            setTimeout(() => {
                startCountdown();
                // set to 16h later
                countDownDate = countDownDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 16);
            }, (1000 * 60)) // 1m test
        }
    });

startCountdown();}}
```

Comment: Tried to turn it into a snippet but I'm getting basic syntax errors. Did you check the browser console?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah, I just checked it and got a syntax error. I fixed it but still, nothing shows up when I insert the code.

Comment: I'm getting `now is not defined` inside the getTom function, since it's not defined. Did you write this code? Or just find it somewhere?